# How to convert multiple columns into JSON and group them by another column in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following columns
`['order_number','line_item_id','reason','quantity','status']`

I need to combine these columns `['line_item_id','reason','quantity','status']` into JSON and group them by `['order_number']` so it looks gives a df like this instead:

```
['order_number', 'line_items']

  0123445      , {"line_item_id":"value","reason":"value","quantity":"value","status":"value"}
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

The furthest I can get is:

`lines.to_json()` but this puts my whole df into a json string.

Code so far:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
import json
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

file = pd.read_csv('DDB.csv')

lines = pd.DataFrame(file)

print(lines.head())

lines.drop(['return_id','customer_id','order_date','return_status','created_at'], axis =1, inplace = True)


lines = lines.to_json()

print(lines)
```

example of data:

[image]

Comment: please show a sample of your data.

Comment: @Manakin please see link at bottom of post, thanks for getting back to me

Comment: this is not a [mcve] please read [ask] and format your question

Comment: I've sorted it thanks, but it's not hard to produce an empty data frame and pass dummy data into it. All I wanted to know how to merge columns b,c,d,e into json format and group it by column a. 

You can throw whatever data you want into the columns. If you are unable to do that then maybe this question wasnt for you

Comment: On SO, always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. Only plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Otherwise your question is likely to be downvoted and closed. If your question is closed in this way, you are barred from asking question for a period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have dataframe of following structure:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'order_number': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'line_item_id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'reason': ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5'],
    'quantity': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
    'status': ['ok', 'ok', 'error', 'ok', 'ok']
                   
})

df.head()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Parse dataframe to json:

```
d = { f"{df.loc[i]['order_number']}" : {
    'line_item_id' : df.loc[i]['line_item_id'],
    'reason' : df.loc[i]['reason'],
    'quantity' : str(df.loc[i]['quantity']),
    'status' : df.loc[i]['status']
    } for i in df.index }

result = json.dumps(d)

print(result)
```

When parsing, you may encounter exceptions like "Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable", which means that some columns need to be cast to int or string. In this example column "quantity" is casted to string.

Output:

```
{
    "1": {
        "line_item_id": "a",
        "reason": "r1",
        "quantity": "100",
        "status": "ok"
    },
    "2": {
        "line_item_id": "b",
        "reason": "r2",
        "quantity": "200",
        "status": "ok"
    },
    "3": {
        "line_item_id": "c",
        "reason": "r3",
        "quantity": "300",
        "status": "error"
    },
    "4": {
        "line_item_id": "d",
        "reason": "r4",
        "quantity": "400",
        "status": "ok"
    },
    "5": {
        "line_item_id": "e",
        "reason": "r5",
        "quantity": "500",
        "status": "ok"
    }
}
```